# python decorator extract argument

Tags: python, decorator

I am new to decorators and trying to write one that allows me to get the named argument, if it exists, otherwise Exception or something.

To explain:

```
# my decorator!
def test_mem(key, modifier):
    def deco(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            # something here, s.t.
            # print(args + modifier) <------
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
return deco
```

## my function

```
@test_mem('username', modifier = '_allowed')
def myfunc(arg1, username = None, stuff = None):
    # logic, this code is always run!
    return 'Done'

myfunc(1, 3)
>>>> '3_allowed'
myfunc(1, username = 3)
>>>> '3_allowed'
myfunc(1, stuff = [])
>>>> Exception
```

When I coded it, my example 1 and example 2 were mutually exclusive, when example 1 worked example 2 broke and vice versa.  I am trying to use this to create some automatic keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may also want to consider [`inspect.getcallargs()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.getcallargs). Inside your decorator, you can use:

```
dictionary = inspect.getcallargs(func, *args, **kwargs)
dictionary['username']  # Gets you the username, default or modifed
```

To copy from the linked Python docs:

```
>>> from inspect import getcallargs
>>> def f(a, b=1, *pos, **named):
...     pass
>>> getcallargs(f, 1, 2, 3)
{'a': 1, 'named': {}, 'b': 2, 'pos': (3,)}
>>> getcallargs(f, a=2, x=4)
{'a': 2, 'named': {'x': 4}, 'b': 1, 'pos': ()}
>>> getcallargs(f)
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
TypeError: f() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)
```